# Proposed tag synonym: [trumpet-or-cornet] = [trumpet]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, retagging

We currently have a [trumpet](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trumpet) tag, but there are a variety of questions for cornet which do not currently have an effective tag. I've created a [trumpet-or-cornet](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trumpet-or-cornet) tag and proposed it as a synonym for [trumpet](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trumpet) with the idea that [trumpet-or-cornet](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trumpet-or-cornet) would become the primary tag, and the cornet-related questions could then be retagged to use it.

Cornet and trumpet are similar enough, and used interchangeably enough, that having one tag to cover both seems reasonable.

---

You can vote on whether to accept or reject the synonym [here](https://music.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms?tab=Score&dir=Descending&filter=Suggested).